# Javascript multiple update the same field

Tags: javascript, jquery

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/hReB3/6/

Javascript code:

```
$('#qty').keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val() != '' && isNumber($(this).val()) && $(this).val() > 0)
    {
    var price = $('#real_price').val() * 1;
    var qty = $(this).val() * 1;

    var total = price * qty;
    $('#price').html(total);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#price').html('500');    
    }
});

function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

If I'm updating the price for the first field, it works fine, but for the second doesnt.

I'm new into javascript :).

Comment: You can't give the same ID to two elements. Use classes instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wXG7F/1/)

Using classes on your fields instead of IDs (IDs must be unique) and enclosing them within a parent `DIV` would allow you to use this code and gives you scope to add as many sections to your page as you need.

HTML

```
<div>
    Price $<span class="price">500</span>

    <input type="hidden" class="real_price" value="500" />
    <input type="text" class="qty" value="1" />
</div>
<div>
    Price $<span class="price">500</span>

    <input type="hidden" class="real_price" value="500" />
    <input type="text" class="qty" value="1" />
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.qty').keyup(function () {
    var $me = $(this),
        $parent = $me.parent('div'),
        total = 500;

    if (isNumber($me.val()) && $me.val() > 0) 
    {
        var price = $parent.find('.real_price').val() * 1,
            qty = $me.val() * 1;

        total = price * qty;           
    }
    $parent.find('.price').html(total);
});
```

You could also replace your hidden fields with `data-price` attributes as shown here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wXG7F/2/)

Comment: Selected as an answer, it's exactly what I need! Also, I need to update the total cart prices. I already tried to make a new total_price var, and then total_price += total but it doesn't show me the total price on the page. It doesn't update the price on the page if i insert the total_price class into a new <div> but if i insert in every already created div it works. Can you give me a little help? I think I miss something..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="text" id="qty1" value="1"/><br />
<input type="text" id="qty2" value="1"/>

$('#qty1,#qty2').keyup(function(){})
```

And in the price evaluation time replace this with

```
$('#price').html(total);
```

with

```
($(this).attr('id')=="qty1") ? $('#price1').html(total) : $('#price2').html(total);
```

Comment: The prices are automatically generated from a SQL database. I don't know the number of those imputs on the page. Could be 1 or could be 10.

Comment: just maintain different ids for the price evaluation tag and input fields that's fine

Comment: @marius use good name conventions that's fine, if you are using item1 as id for the input field one, then for the price evaluation label use priceitem1 as id then you can easily write a general function even for 100 fields

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, You can't able to use `id` value in more elements, instead that you can use `classname` etc, I have updated your fiddle code,

HTML:

```
    Price $<span id="price_qty_1">500</span>
    <input type="hidden" id="real_price_qty_1" value="500" />
    <input type="text" id="qty_1" class="qty" value="1"/><br />
    Price $<span id="price_qty_2">500</span>
    <input type="hidden" id="real_price_qty_2" value="500" />
    <input type="text" id="qty_2" class="qty" value="1"/>
```

Jquery:

```
    $('.qty').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val() != '' && isNumber($(this).val()) && $(this).val() > 0)
        {

        var idAt = $(this).attr('id'); 
        var price = $('#real_price_'+idAt).val() * 1;
        var qty = $(this).val() * 1;

        var total = price * qty;
        $('#price_'+idAt).html(total);
        }
        else
        {
        $('#price_'+idAt).html('500');    
        }
    });

    function isNumber(n) {
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
    }
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hReB3/10/